# multithreaded merge of pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

(am new to python/pandas but am otherwise experienced programmer - I would know how to do below in a number of other languages - would appreciate pointers to what I should learn for python/pandas)

```
X1, X2, ..., Xn = small dataframes (say about 10k rows)
Y = a large dataframe (say about 10 million rows)
```

I have a loop right now:

```
for i=1 to n:
  Zi = Xi.merge(Y, how='left', on='common_key')
```

(note that Zi will be small like Xi)

This, I think, should be an easily parallelizable problem except with one gotcha - since Y is large, I don't want to spawn lots of processes each with its copy of Y (i will run out of memory). Instead, since each piece of work (merge) requires only read-only access to Y, I would love to be able to spawn a lot of threads each with read-only access to Y, its own copy of Xi and collect it all into a vector of Zs. But then I run into the "GIL-lock" question and questions about whether pandas merge is multi-threadable or not (and multi-thread safe or not).

What's the most fruitful thing to focus on learning that can lead to a nice solution for above please?

Thanks!
cq
==== @John Zwinck makes the absolutely fair point that I should tune the single-threaded version first. So below are timings following his suggestion of adding indexes - it's slightly (~15%) better but not significantly so that my problem disappears. So I think the question remains open.

```
Y.shape
(8863606, 5)

X.shape
(5860, 28)

indexed_Y = Y.set_index('common_key')
Wall time: 131 ms

indexed_X = X.set_index('common_key')
Wall time: 1.99 ms

# base case = merge, no indices
X.merge(Y, on='common_key', how='left').shape
Wall time: 5.8 s

# using on-the-fly-indexed Y improves by about 7% from base case
X.merge(Y, how='left', left_on='common_key', right_on=pd.Index(Y['common_key'])).shape
Wall time: 5.4 s

# using "pre-indexed" Y improves by about 15% from base case
X.merge(indexed_Y, how='left', left_on='common_key', right_index=True).shape
Wall time: 4.93 s

sorted_indexed_Y = indexed_Y.sort_index()
# pre-sorting doesn't improve things any more
X.merge(sorted_indexed_Y, how='left', left_on='common_key', right_index=True).shape
Wall time: 4.96 s
```

Comment: What is `Y.common_key.dtype` (i.e. what is the type you're merging on)?

Comment: You might want to try the tricks here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/tkm2261/fast-pandas-left-join-357x-faster-than-pd-merge/notebook

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the multithreading aspect because I think your real goal is to speed this up.  In Python and Pandas it's a good idea to speed things up without threads if possible.

You have this loop:

```
for i=1 to n:
  Zi = Xi.merge(Y, how='left', on='common_key')
```

Let's think about what this is doing.  It has to loop through each Xi and then find each `Y.common_key`.  Pandas can't assume `Y.common_key` is sorted, so it must either do linear search for each row in Xi, or it must build an index of `Y.common_key`.  In either case, it should be much faster to build an index of `Y.common_key` just once and use it repeatedly.

A simple solution might look something like this:

```
Y.set_index('common_key', inplace=True) # or store in Y2 without inplace
for i=1 to n:
  Zi = Xi.merge(Y, how='left', left_on='common_key', right_index=True)
```

Now for each row in Xi it will do a fast lookup using `Y.index`.  You may be able to use `right_on=pd.Index(Y.common_key)` instead of `set_index()` and `right_index`, but I haven't tried that and the Pandas docs aren't clear on whether an Index can be used with `right_on` efficiently or not.  Please try both ways and let us know what speedups you get.

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your absolutely fair suggestion that one should tune the single-threaded version first - I did that using indexes as you suggest which gives about 15% speedup and also tried sorting which doesn't improve (original question edited to add details above). 

Appreciate any further tuning suggestions (or learning material pointers specific to this case) and/or thoughts on the original question if you think multi-threading/processing is the next step. Thanks again!